# Mutate the value

Tags: function, pointers, go

Can someone please tell me how to mutate the value of 
**type Clock**.

Basically when I call **New()** I get the output **3:04** and after calling **ADD()** function I expect the value to be **03:09**. If I assign the value of **ADD()** function call  then I get **03:09** as output. I was wondering is it possible to mutate the value of the **type Clock** using pointers?

```
package main

import "fmt"

const testVersion = 4

type Clock int

func New(hour, minute int) Clock {
    result := (hour*60 + minute) % (24*60)
    if result < 0 {
        result = result + 24*60
    }

    return Clock(result)
}

func (c Clock) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%02v:%02v", int(c/60), int(c%60))
}

func (c Clock) Add(minutes int) Clock{
    newC:=New(0,minutes + int(c))
    //fmt.Println(a)
}

func main() {
    result := New(3, 4)
    fmt.Println(result)
    result.Add(5)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. If you are going to modify the value, you must define `Add` method on pointer receiver, e.g.

```
func (c *Clock) Add(minutes int) Clock{
    *c =New(0,minutes + int(*c))

    return *c
}
```

Basic rule is: use pointer receiver if you're going to change the receiver value (except for `slice` and `map` which act as reference). Take a look at the following materials for better understanding on method receiver:

1. The Go tour on [Methods](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1)
2. FAQ: [Should I define methods on values or pointers?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers)

Comment: i was trying to use pointer receiver.but should n't we accessing c as int(&c) instead of int(*c)?Sorry if it's naive question my background is in python

Comment: The `&` operator will give you the `address` of a variable i.e. it generates a pointer. The `*` operator will give you `the value` pointed by the pointer. Take a look at [Pointers](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1).

Comment: thanks for the detail explanation .Since Add function is returning pointer(return *c) I don't understand why ADD function is not throwing error because in function return value I put Clock not *Clock